# Write C# program to calculate Halsted Metric in Given c# source file

Tags: c#

I want to write a application to calculate Halsted Metric in Given c# source file. I cant find a method to calculate these parameters.

- the number of distinct operators
- the number of distinct operands
- the total number of operators
- the total number of operands

are there way to calculate these parameters in given c# source file?

Comment: Are you unclear as to what an operator or operand is?  If I have an expression like x = y + 1 there are 3 operands and 2 operators.

Comment: No, actualy i am clear with what are the operators & operands. the problems is how to calculate those programically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what I can really advise you is Irony which is a really nice project for parsing formal languages. I've used it in my own project and was pleased by its flexibility and speed. [Here](http://irony.codeplex.com/) is the link to their codeplex page where you can download sources and ask any questions regarding the project,